# how to get files count in a directory using ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, directory

using ruby how to get number of files in a given Directory,the file count should include count from recursive directories.

Eg: folder1(2 files) -----> folder2(4 files)
    and folder2 is inside folder1. 
total count for above case should be 6 files.

is there any function in ruby which fetch me this count.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The fastest way should be (not including directories in count):

```
Dir.glob(File.join(your_directory_as_variable_or_string, '**', '*')).select { |file| File.file?(file) }.count
```

And shorter:

```
dir = '~/Documents'
Dir[File.join(dir, '**', '*')].count { |file| File.file?(file) }
```

Comment: Can you explain why the first method should be faster than the second? Or maybe I misunderstood what you meant by "the fastest way".

Comment: The shorter one used more Ruby syntactic sugar than the first one, that' all ;)

Comment: Both of these solutions return 0 for me on OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Try using a full path, then it works for me even under Mavericks.

Comment: Even shorter: `Dir[File.join dir, '**', '*'].count &File.method(:file?)`.

Answer (score 29):

All you need is this, run in the current directory.

```
Dir["**/*"].length
```

It counts directories as files.

Answer (score 8):

A slight modification and a comment

```
Dir['**/*'].count { |file| File.file?(file) }
```

works for me in Ruby 1.9.3, and is shorter.

A caveat, at least on my Windows 7 box, is that `Dir['somedir/**/*']` doesn't work.  I have to use

```
cd(somedir) { Dir['**/*'] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also go super bare bones and do a system command:

```
count = `ls -1 #{dir} | wc -l`.to_i
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

`find . -typef|wc -l`

Also, what are the downsides of using this over Dir.count method?

Comment: This command is not portable as it may not work on Windows and other platform which do not provide one of the above mentioned commands.

Comment: Actually most answers here would not work on windows because they use forward slash `/`

Comment: Windows now supports forward slash, doesn't it? Just clarifying for future readers...

Answer (score 1):

Just now had to find a way to get a list of files from a network share that was taking long with Dir.glob, Filelist from the rake gem seems to be the solution, benchmark follows. Share is on a windows server, script eran on a Windows 10 desktop, Ruby 2.3.0 X64. Netork share had 754 files, frow which 320 CSV's where I was looking for. Some of the files were in subfolders.

```
require 'rake'
require 'benchmark'

source_path = '//server/share/**/*.csv'
puts FileList.new(source_path).size #320
puts Dir.glob(source_path).length #320
puts Dir[source_path].length #320

Benchmark.bm do |x| 
  x.report("FileList  ") { 1.times { FileList.new(source_path) } }
  x.report("Dir.glob  ") { 1.times { Dir.glob(source_path) } }
  x.report("Dir[]     ") { 1.times { Dir[source_path] } } 
end
```

Gives

```
       user     system      total        real
FileList    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000073)
Dir.glob    0.031000   0.406000   0.437000 ( 11.324227)
Dir[]       0.047000   0.563000   0.610000 ( 11.887771)
```

Old answer:

Fastest way in windows for very big folders would be to use the [command line version of search everything](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/command_line_interface/) like this, don't know if Linux has something like Search Everything.. If it does, please let us know.

```
ES = 'C:\Users\...\everything\es\es.exe'

def filelist path
  command = %Q{"#{ES}" "#{path}\\*"}
  list = []
  IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |pipe|
    while lijn = pipe.gets
      list << lijn
    end
  end
  list
end

filelist(path).count
```

see here the results for a relatively small folder (+800 files)

```
Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report("glob      ") { filelist(path).count }
  x.report("everything") { Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/*").count } 
end 

Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
glob         0.000000   0.032000   0.032000 (  0.106887)
everything   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001979)
------------------------------------- total: 0.032000sec

                 user     system      total        real
glob         0.016000   0.015000   0.031000 (  0.110030)
everything   0.000000   0.016000   0.016000 (  0.001881)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `~/Documents` as example.

One line code:

`Dir['~/Documents'].length`

For longer paths one line can be less readable, so:

`path = '~/Documents/foo/bar'`

`Dir[path].length`

Answer (score 1):

The current best answer does not count files in subdirectories starting with '.'.
When we want to count files in subdirectories like '.git' or '.vs' then we need to use File::FNM_DOTMATCH argument but I am just beginner here not having 50 points so I can comment the best answer.

```
def folder_count(folder_path)
  Dir.glob("#{folder_path}/**/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH).count { |file| File.file?(file) }
end
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D

"Note, this will not match Unix-like hidden files (dotfiles). In order to include those in the match results, you must use the File::FNM_DOTMATCH flag or something like "{*,.*}"."

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
//we suppose that the variable folder1 is an absolute path here
pattern = File.join(folder1, "**", "*")
count = Dir.glob(pattern).count
```