# Any Chef cookbook to get the number of files in a/all folder/s

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

is there any cookbook for Chef that counts the files in all folders on Linux systems? Or any other solution?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. That's not really the core focus of Chef. As you can code anything that Ruby can, you might look more into that space. Try that and ask again when you run into concrete issues.

Comment: What is your use case, you're asking an XY problem there. This question is an attempt to solve something in a way that sounds weird, it is not a problem in itself but we can not help/give advice without a larger picture of which problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773413/how-to-get-files-count-in-a-directory-using-ruby

Comment: you don't even need a cookbook for this. write up a recipe using what JackChance provided above.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can say confidently there is no cookbook for this, you'll have to write it yourself.